# CSS scroll snapping

Tags: html, css

I know that this has probably been answered before, but I have been looking for 4 hours and can't find a working answer. Sorry if this is redundant.

I am trying to create a website where the page is divided into divs, each div having the height and width of a full page. I want to use CSS scroll snapping to load the divs one full page at a time. I'm using a wordpress theme so I don't have direct access to the overarching div layout or the body, etc. So My idea was to create a custom html div inside the page and essentially build my page inside that.

However, I cannot get my proof of concept working. I've successfully taken scroll control away from body, but the div doesn't scroll at all, much less snap.

I'm pretty new to this, so any help or feed back is greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.
Also, as I've said, I'm new to this and haven't gotten around to learning JavaScript yet. But I've read this is possible with pure CSS.

EDIT: I am using Firefox 88 to display, but I've also tried Chrome 90.

Here's the code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.parent-container div {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100vw;

}

.full div {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
}

.full:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSS Practice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="parent-container">

            <div class="full">First</div>
            <div class="full">Second</div>
            <div class="full">Third</div>
        </div>

    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="full">First</div>
  <div class="full">Second</div>
  <div class="full">Third</div>
</div>

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parent-container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.full {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}
.full:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #333;
}
```

Working sample: https://codepen.io/sapm/pen/bGgJgmb
removing the div selector from .full selector in the rules seemed to work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I was including them. Like I said, pretty new.